# for loop with switch statements

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, switch-statement

I am relatively new to C/C++ and i was wondering how I could use  for loop so I wouldn't have to make a bunch of switch statements I have already made the switch statement I just need help on integrating the for loop into it. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable :   4996)   
int main()  {
    char    ch;
    ch = getchar();
    int f, a = 10, b = 20;
    printf("ch  =   %c\n", ch);


    switch (ch) {
    case '+':   f = a + b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
    case '-':   f = a - b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
    case '*':   f = a * b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
    case '/':   f = a / b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
    default:    printf("invalid operator\n");
    }

}
```

the purpose of the program is to enter in either +,-,*,/ and then based on that input it will execute the case that was entered in so + would add a and be together.

Comment: What does "without using breaks" in the comment refer to? I can see at least one break,

Comment: What's the intention of this code? Can you provide an input and the expected output?

Comment: What use is a `for` loop in your calculator program when only one case is executed?

Comment: You could have one array of operators and one array of function pointers, loop round and compare, then call the appropriate function ;)

Comment: @DaniEne you should have edited out the "without using breaks" comment, instead of editing out the `break` statements!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to map operator characters to operations.

Your current code represents that mapping via execution flow control.

In C++ the standard library's `map` collection is a good choice for instead representing it as data, so that you don't even need to use a loop. In C an array of structs where each contains a `char` and a function pointer, can do the same job. However, you then have to define the functions yourself, because unlike the C++ standard library the C standard library doesn't provide convenient named functions for the arithmetic operations.

---

In a similar fashion, a Boolean state, whether something is true or false, can be represented as an execution position or as data, usually as a variable of type `bool`. What to choose is mainly engineering gut feeling. Sometimes representation via flow control is simplest and most clear, sometimes representation as data is simplest and most clear.

---

C++ example, mostly reproducing the given example code's effect, but with the mapping as data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    const map<char, function<int(int,int)>> op =
    {
        { '+', plus<int>() },
        { '-', minus<int>() },
        { '*', multiplies<int>() },
        { '/', divides<int>() }
    };

    char  ch;
    cout << "Operator? ";  cin >> ch;
    cout << "ch = '" << ch << "'\n";

    if( op.count( ch ) == 0 )
    {
        cout << "invalid operator\n";
    }
    else
    {
        const int a = 10;
        const int b = 20;
        cout << "f   =   " << op.at( ch )( a, b ) << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Corresponding C example, which does include a `for` loop as mentioned in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int plus( int a, int b )        { return a+b; }
int minus( int a, int b )       { return a-b; }
int multiplies( int a, int b )  { return a*b; }
int divides( int a, int b )     { return a/b; }

typedef int(*Func_ptr)(int, int);

struct Mapping
{
    char        ch;
    Func_ptr    f;
};

const struct Mapping op[] =
{
    { '+', plus },
    { '-', minus },
    { '*', multiplies },
    { '/', divides }
};

const int n_ops = sizeof( op )/sizeof( *op );

Func_ptr op_at( char ch )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n_ops; ++i )
    {
        if( op[i].ch == ch ) { return op[i].f; }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{

    int  ch;        // Note: type `int` to accommodate EOF value.
    printf( "Operator? " );  ch = getchar();
    printf( "ch = '%c'\n", ch );

    if( op_at( ch ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "invalid operator\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        const int a = 10;
        const int b = 20;
        printf( "f   =   %d\n", op_at( ch )( a, b ) );
    }
}
```

C11, I think it was, introduced some machinery for effectively overloading functions so they can be used much like overloaded functions in C++. I don't remember much about and didn't use it here. I would suggest that if you need to handle different data types, just use different function names.

---

Note that the C example also compiles as C++, so both these examples are technically C++. However, the last example is in C style, using C idioms and C i/o, and does things that are unnecessary in C++. We usually just say that such code is C, not that it's C style; such code might not always compile as C++, because while C is largely a subset of C++ these are *two different, separate languages*: there is technically no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: This is an object lesson in "do not dual tag with C and C++ if you don't want a C++ answer".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks, both for the edit and the note about tags. I didn't notice the dual language. Will create a C example also, then.

Answer (score 1):

> i was wondering how I could use for loop so I wouldn't have to make a bunch of switch statements I have already made the switch statement I just need help on integrating the for loop into it.

A `for` loop is used to repeat a block of statements until a condition is met.

A `switch` statement is used for making a decision about which block of statements to run based on a given value, instead of using a bunch of `if` statements.

It doesn't make sense to **replace** a `switch` statement with a `for` loop. What does make sense is using a `switch` statement **inside of** a loop, to act on something that the loop generates, like asking for user input.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable :   4996)   

int main()  {
    int f, a = 10, b = 20;
    char ch;
    int finished = 0;

    do {
        ch = getchar();
        printf("ch  =   %c\n", ch);

        switch (ch) {
            case '+':   f = a + b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
            case '-':   f = a - b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
            case '*':   f = a * b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
            case '/':   f = a / b;  printf("f   =   %d\n", f); break;
            case 'q':   finished = 1; break;
            default:    printf("invalid operator\n"); break;
        }
    }
    while (!finished);

    return 0;
}
```